# C# how to move items of listview1 from usercontrol to another listview of usercontrol

Tags: c#, user-controls, listviewitem

Is it possible or is there any way to transfer the ListViewItems from usercontrol(child) to the another usercontrol(Parent) how could i do that without instances to parent? because i want to transfer the data from the listview of the child to pass on its parent. i cant instance parent because the parent is already showed but disabled. when my child usercontrol is closed or disposed, the parent will be enabled again how can i move my items from the child to its parent ?

P.S: Usercontrol1 is the parent of Usercontrol2

Comment: A bit more clarity on the question would be helpful to solve your issue.

Comment: @GeekyCoder check my edited.

Comment: yes it is possible. but you will need references and/or helper function.. disabling the an lv doesn't prevent it from receiving items through code.

Comment: @TaW i did the ref function and it works little bit, it says that listviewitem cannot passed as an out or ref what should i do?

Comment: A function to move a listviewitem can be as simple as this : `public void moveItem(ListView lv1, int oldIndex, ListView lv2, int newIndex)
    {
        oldIndex = Math.Min(oldIndex, lv1.Items.Count-1);
        ListViewItem lvi = lv1.Items[oldIndex];
        lv1.Items.RemoveAt(oldIndex);
        lv2.Items.Insert(Math.Min(newIndex, lv2.Items.Count), lvi);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think this is right i ended up in using this code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[,] name = new string[listView1.Items.Count,2];//  
        for(int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)       //
        {                                                    // This will insert the items from the listview to array
            name[i,0] = listView1.Items[i].Text;             //
            name[i, 1] = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text;//
        }                                                    //
        ucAddBook.pass(ref name);//called the method from parent and set name as reference in parameter
        this.Dispose();//this will trigger the parent to loop the array that i pass then insert in the listview
    }
```

this is the code from parent

```
    public static string[,] mylist { get; set; }// i set the array to static so if the usercontrol is already disposed the array wont get reset to null
    public void pass(ref string[,] name)        // this is where the array designated
    {
        mylist = name;
    }
    private void usercon_AddBook_ControlRemoved(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        panel2.Enabled = true;
        for (int i = 0; i <mylist.Length/2; i++)                //  
        {                                                       //
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(mylist[i, 0]); // this will insert the items from array to listview
            item.SubItems.Add(mylist[i, 1]);                    //
            listView1.Items.Add(item);                          //
        }                                                       //
    }
```

Please let me know if my code needs an improvements; thanks;

**NOTE:** I updated the for loop i changed it from mylist.Length-1 to mylist.Length/2 because im using 2d array so the lenght would doubleup thats why i divide it into 2,so my array will not going to out of range.

Comment: If this works, fine. If it doesn't hen it isn't an answer and you should move the code to your question.

Comment: @Taw should i remove this and move to my question? sorry for asking im new here.

Comment: Yes, unless it actually __does__ answer the question. If it does, then it is a valid answer and you should leave it! I was unsure because of the comment about it _working only a little_

Comment: @TaW oh, yes this code works.  Sorry i misunderstood your comment. Ill just leave it here